# iPad Device Height JQuery

Tags: jquery, ipad, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm building a web app through the iPad in kiosk mode using the 320 and up framework.

I'm using media queries, yet currently I've had to set the page wrapper width & height in pixels (1024 x 768 as per the iPad in landscape) to allow for everything else to be in relative dimensions.

Rather than having fixed pixels, is there a way that I can set the height using JQuery detection? The width works fine, however I need a value for the height so that the rest of the design can be positioned based on that.

Any help would be awesome. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/) is a good resource for what the various height and width functions will output. Open it on the iPad and it will show you the values.

You are probably looking for `window.screen.height`.